# Can I say 'I feel connected' when I think a movie tells my story?

Tags: adjectives, phrase-requests

Recently I saw a movie that tells a story very similar to mine. I wanted to tell my friends about it and said 'I felt connected'. They doubted if that is the right word to use, since the word 'connected' is more often used to describe a romantic relationship. So my question is, what would be a good word for this situation?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think *connected* too unusual a word to use in that context; however, one phrase that does not have romantic connotations is [*to identify with*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/identify+with), as in "I identified with the protagonist." There are also the phrases *to have a rapport with* and *to empathize with.*

**Edit:** Just thought of the phrase [*to relate to*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/relate) and I like it much better. All the above can be clumsy when talking about a story instead of a character. *To relate to* is more general.